# how to stub a method in a class which is called from another class

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, stub

```
public class A {
    .
    .
    .
    public static String methodA() {
        String x = new B().methodX();
        return x + "how are ya?";
    }
}
public class B {
    .
    .
    public String methodX() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}

@Test
public void testGreeting() {
    final B b = Mockito.spy(new B());
    Mockito.when(b.methodX()).thenReturn("Hi!");

    String greetings = A.methodA();
    // greetings -> "Hello" but i want it to be "Hi!".
}
```

I'm not able to get my method to return the desired value.
Above implementations shows how I have written my test, but it's not working.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Either you inject `b` inside that instance of `A` (by hand or with an injection framework) or you can spy the whole class instead of an instance, as in `Mockito.spy(B.class);`. Option 1 is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet to clarify given answers: your mistake is that you do not actually use that spy/mock anywhere.

In your class A you have a static method where a new B is always instantiated instead of using your spy:

```
String x = new B().methodX();
```

Spy does not make class somehow globally *spied* but creates just one instance that is spied and can be mocked. And yet again: this `new B()` is not a spy nor mock.

One *possible* working solution would be to change your design a bit (as already suggested) and let Mockito inject this spied B in an instance of A:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    public static class AlternativeA {
        // this B can be injected and replaced with a spy or mock
        private B b = new B();
        // get rid of static to use spied B
        public String methodA() {
            String x = b.methodX();
            return x + "how are ya?";
        }
    }

    // Using annotations to create and inject mocks
    @Spy
    private B b;
    @InjectMocks
    private AlternativeA a;
    
    @Test
    public void testGreeting() {
        Mockito.when(b.methodX()).thenReturn("Hi!");
        String greetings = a.methodA();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer writen by wakio, instead of your code, you can write :

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public String methodA() {
        String x = b.methodX();
        return x + "how are ya?";
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class B {
    public String methodX() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}

@Test
public void testGreeting() {
    B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
    Mockito.when(b.methodX()).thenReturn("Hi!");

    A a = new A();
    a.setB(b);

    String greetings = a.methodA();
    // The result will be "Hi!"
}
```